# How are angular routes built and handled?

Tags: javascript, angular, build, routes

I'm having some fundimental conceptual difficulties with angular.

Suppose I have multiple routes in a Angular app, like `/` (root), `/cart`, `/map`.

The way I understand angular apps are build and bundled for production is,  that webpack or a similar service pack everything into one directory.

The way I undestand angular apps are run on the server is that a server is pointed to a directory where the output of the built angular app resides as static content.

Now let say I make a request to `/cart`; my server has no knownledge of this route; how is this supposed to work ?

My question is how do I make the bridge between angular and server routes ?

How do I have to configure my server routes ?

Do I catch all my angular routes and point them to the `index.html` file compiled by webpack and let angular detect  on which route it currently is ?

What is considered best practice and what are some common pitfalls ?

Comment: All you need is placed here https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: @yurzui post it as an answer and I'll accept for SEO purposes